# How to find the limit of a complex function?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

I just wanted to make sure I was doing this problem correctly because my professor did not give us many examples in class.

So, I know that $\displaystyle{\lim_{z \to 0}\overline{z}/z }$ does not exist, but if I wanted to know if $\displaystyle{\lim_{z \to 3}\overline{z}/z }=1$?

Since my class is not really a proofs class, he told us that we only needed to check to see if the limit did not exist when the denominator would be "bad" as $z$ approaches a certain number (his words, not mine). If the limit is not "bad," then we would just find the limit by plugging the number into the function. Is it okay to do that? What is the official way to find the limit?

Comment: *Continuous* (at a point) are functions in which the limit at that point can be computed by evaluating the function at that point. Polynomials are continuous functions. Quotients of continuous functions are also continuous functions, as long as the denominator doesn't vanish at that point. $z$ is a polynomial in its real and imaginary part, and so is $\overline{z}$. So, they are continuous at $3$. Since $z$ doesn't vanish at $3$, then $\overline{z}/z$ is also continuous at $3$. Therefore the limit of $\overline{z}/z$ at $3$ is obtained by evaluating it at $3$.

Comment: I hope you are not paying for that education.